# How to allow pam radius module in centos for user's password as well as one time password

Tags: pam

I have a problem with the PAM Radius module. Actually, I have it installed already under CentOS. I've inserted the line:

```
auth  required /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and commented out the line:

```
@include common-auth.
```

After that, I've edited the file `/etc/raddb/server` and entered the radius server's IP and restarted the `ssh` service.

Now, I enter the username and the OTP (One-Time Password), it's accepted just as expected. However, when I enter the user's password, It is not accepting the user's password.

I'd like to have PAM setup so that a user can use either their password or the OTP. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found this document which used slightly different options when configuring PAM. I'd start by trying these out. The document is titled: [DualShield for PAM RADIUS 
Implementation Guide (Version 5.4)](http://www.deepnetsecurity.com/download/dualshield/docs/PAM%20RADIUS%20-%20Implementation%20Guide.pdf).

*excerpt*

> 1. open the configuration file `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` or `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, in a text editor
> 2. locate the line below:
>
>    ```
>    auth substack password-auth
>    ```
> 3. insert the line below:
>
>    ```
>    auth sufficient pam_radius_auth.so
>    ```
>
>    i.e.:
>
>    ```
>    auth sufficient pam_radius_auth.so 
>    auth substack password-auth
>    ```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..Now,I have successfully logged in with user's password as well as one time password.

Comment: @RohitSingh - that's great news, glad your issue's been resolved. You can mark this A as accepted so other's know your issue's been solved.

Comment: Here is one more query that is how can I login with user's one time password after user's password on a single screen??? I hope you understand..??  let me give you a description below:

Comment: Username:rohit Password:.... OTP : .... on a single screen.

Comment: This is a new Q. Please start another one.